# ionotifywait on shared folder

Tags: bash, samba

I have set up a bash script on an Ubuntu 10.04 server that generates a new PDF whenever a PDF is created in the `./incoming/` directory on this server, the new PDF is created in the `./outgoing/` folder.  Both of these folders are on the local machine and are shared with samba version 3.4.7. The script uses `inotifywait` to watch the incoming directory (as per [Script to monitor folder for new files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files)).

```
inotifywait -m ./incoming/ -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        # Generate PDF using $file into ./outgoing/
    done
```

This works fine when I copy a file either using bash or Windows explorer, but when I save a `test.pdf` attachment from MS Outlook (or Word) on Windows 7 clients I get a several activations;

```
The file './in/test.pdf' appeared in directory './incoming/' via 'CREATE'
The file './in/B90C4C41.tmp' appeared in directory './incoming/' via 'CREATE'
The file './in/BE5AC54E.tmp' appeared in directory './incoming/' via 'MOVED_TO'
The file './in/test.pdf' appeared in directory './incoming/' via 'MOVED_TO'
```

Why is it doing this? How can I prevent it? Or should I just work around it with `sleep` and ignore the `.tmp` files?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore non-PDF files, since you probably can't do anything about temp files that are created in the directory.

```
while read path action file; do
    [[ $file = *.pdf ]] || continue
    echo "..."
done
```